# Links being stripped from Open Graph custom action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently Facebook started stripping the links from the "message" attribute in my Open Graph actions and so the links are not showing any more when you share the action on your wall.

I think they might be doing that so that the "message" attribute stays clean of my marketing. Is there an other way to promote the real URL of the content ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *linked action* property of an Open Graph action: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/action-links/

This will add a link under the OG action user see in the feed linking to an URL you define with a label you define. For example "Add yours", "Save this recipe", etc.

Comment: For this I need to create a new action though, and it will then send an SSL connection to a specific endpoint URL, with a signed_request. Seems a bit overkill to redirect the user to another url no ?